# Clear Results Div of Php Live MySQL Database Search (not input field)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Sorry, I must be missing something really basic.  I want to clear the results DIV after a search.  I can either do it with a button, or, even better, when the input field is cleared.  Currently if I use this reset button the input field is reset but the results DIV remains on the screen..

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
            /* Get input value on change */
            var term = $(this).val();
            var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
            if(term.length){
                $.get("incl_php/backend-search.php", {query: term}).done(function(data){
                    // Display the returned data in browser
                    resultDropdown.html(data);
                });
            } else{
                resultDropdown.empty();
            }
        });
        
        // Set search input value on click of result item
        $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
            $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
            $(this).parent(".result").empty();
        });
        });
        
        $("#reset").on("click", function() {
            $(".result").empty();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
        <div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search..." />
      <input id="btn" type="button" value="Calculate" name="btn"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input id="reset" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>  
            <div class="result">Test</div>    
     </div> 
</form>
```

When I query the database for results

Or

But when I click reset

The search box is reset but the search results remain

Thanks.

Comment: instead of `empty()` use `.html('');` and check

Comment: try `$(this).parent().find(".result").empty();`

Comment: I updated your question to see if there was an issue. I could not verify one, this looks correct to me. Did you forget to include the jQuery script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Check this example (check and adjust rest of your code accordingly):-***

```js
$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
    var term = $(this).val();
    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
    if(term.length){
            resultDropdown.html(term);
    } else{
        resultDropdown.html('');
    }
});

// Set search input value on click of result item
$(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
    $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
    $(this).parent(".result").html('');
});

$("#reset").on("click", function() {
    $(".result").html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="search-box">
      <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search..." />
      <input id="btn" type="button" value="Calculate" name="btn"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input id="reset" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>     
      <div class="result"></div>    
  </div>  
</form>
```

Try this code once:-

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
        <div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search..." />
            <input id="btn" type="button" value="Calculate" name="btn"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input id="reset" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"/>     
            <div class="result">Test</div>    
        </div>  
</form>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
        /* Get input value on change */
        var term = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if(term.length){
            $.get("incl_php/backend-search.php", {query: term}).done(function(data){
                // Display the returned data in browser
                resultDropdown.html(data);
            });
        } else{
            resultDropdown.html('');
        }
    });

    // Set search input value on click of result item
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").html('');
    });
});

$("#reset").on("click", function() {
    $(".result").html('');
});
</script>
```

Comment: @milwaukee66  glad to help you.